# Unidecode inconsistent behavior when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, pyinstaller, unidecoder

I'm building a script that reads information from a website and manipulates it.

The page may contain some special characters like ã, ç, ó, etc.

In order to simplify decoding issues, I use `unidecode`, like this:

```
# coding=utf-8
from unidecode import unidecode
text = u'Órgão'
print text
print unidecode(text)
raw_input()
```

The above code when executed from console, ie `python test.py` generates the result as:

```
Órgão
Orgao
```

However, if I build an exe using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

and run it, the code generates:

[image]

How do I make pyinstaller exe behave like console?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is explicitly import all additional decoding tables that come with the package like so

```
# This fixes an issue with PyInstaller... is there a more elegant solution perhaps?
from unidecode import x000, x001, x002, x003, x004, x005, x006, x007, x009, x00a,\
    x00b, x00c, x00d, x00e, x00f, x010, x011, x012, x013, x014, x015, x016, x017,\
    x018, x01d, x01e, x01f, x020, x021, x022, x023, x024, x025, x026, x027, x028,\
    x029, x02a, x02c, x02e, x02f, x030, x031, x032, x033, x04d, x04e, x04f, x050,\
    x051, x052, x053, x054, x055, x056, x057, x058, x059, x05a, x05b, x05c, x05d,\
    x05e, x05f, x060, x061, x062, x063, x064, x065, x066, x067, x068, x069, x06a,\
    x06b, x06c, x06d, x06e, x06f, x070, x071, x072, x073, x074, x075, x076, x077,\
    x078, x079, x07a, x07b, x07c, x07d, x07e, x07f, x080, x081, x082, x083, x084,\
    x085, x086, x087, x088, x089, x08a, x08b, x08c, x08d, x08e, x08f, x090, x091,\
    x092, x093, x094, x095, x096, x097, x098, x099, x09a, x09b, x09c, x09d, x09e,\
    x09f, x0a0, x0a1, x0a2, x0a3, x0a4, x0ac, x0ad, x0ae, x0af, x0b0, x0b1, x0b2,\
    x0b3, x0b4, x0b5, x0b6, x0b7, x0b8, x0b9, x0ba, x0bb, x0bc, x0bd, x0be, x0bf,\
    x0c0, x0c1, x0c2, x0c3, x0c4, x0c5, x0c6, x0c7, x0c8, x0c9, x0ca, x0cb, x0cc,\
    x0cd, x0ce, x0cf, x0d0, x0d1, x0d2, x0d3, x0d4, x0d5, x0d6, x0d7, x0f9, x0fa,\
    x0fb, x0fc, x0fd, x0fe, x0ff, x1d4, x1d5, x1d6, x1d7
```

The PyInstaller parser will then include them in the distribution. Note, however, in this case the *data* variable gets imported into your script.

Comment: This also works with `cx_freeze`, where a similar error happens (special chars are removed instead of converted).